# What is the best way to write log data from Kinesis to Cloudwatch?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, log4j, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am working with a resource constrained system and cannot utilize filesystem and network. I am generating some logs in this system and publishing these logs as part of my response. These logs are separated from the response and published to Kinesis.
I have following log data in JsonLayout as payload for Kinesis.

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1503336276808,
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "ERROR",
  "loggerName" : "com.psr",
  "message" : "From tests",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
{
  "timeMillis" : 1503336312411,
  "thread" : "main",
  "level" : "ERROR",
  "loggerName" : "com.psr",
  "message" : "more logs",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "threadId" : 1,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

I want to utilize these logs for metrics and easily searchable in future. Cloudwatch seems to be perfect destination to achieve these goals.

Current Plan is to use AWS lambda and log the payload directly to cloudwatch. This seems not elegant and noisy as time of logs and log group will be wrapped by final logging time in lambda.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

We have done a similar solution using lambda.

We create kinesis as trigger to lambda and we do some cleansing and insert data into elastic search. Using Kibana we search the log data and apply filtering on log data.

As you mentioned you have certain constraints validate this solution is appropriate for you.

You can also look for kinesis firehose integration with elasticsearch